Combine two power bi reports into one pbix file
I have two pbix files (Power BI reports). They have a separate data model, DAX and visualisations.
I want to merge/ combine them into one - so they will still have separate data models and tabs and DAX measures, but they will be in the same file.

That isn't possible. One data model per file.

You may want to look at create a Power BI app from a workspace - with an app you can bring together multiple reports. See Publish an app in Power BI
